# Rsync script that does Daily, Weekly and Monthly backups with hard links

Tags: bash

I have not been able to find a good implementation of using rsync to do daily, weekly and monthly backups with hard links anywhere. So I wrote my own and I am now looking for critique before I set it live on an unRAID production server. Anything I should fix?

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Daily/Weekly/Monthly Backup
#
PROG_NAME=DailyWeeklyMonthlyBackup
BACKUPPOINT=/mnt/user
MOUNTPOINT=/mnt/disks/REDBackup
DAYOFWEEK_NAME=$(date +"%a")
DAYOFWEEK_NUMERAL_WEEKLY=$(date +"%u")
DAYOFWEEK_NUMERAL_MONTHLY=$(date +"%d")

logger Started -t$PROG_NAME $(date "+%m-%d-%Y %r")

if [ -d $MOUNTPOINT ]
then

    # Daily Backup START
    ############################
    rsync -a -v --delete $BACKUPPOINT/ $MOUNTPOINT/Daily/ 2>&1
    logger Daily REDBackup Completed -t$PROG_NAME $(date "+%m-%d-%Y %r")
    /usr/local/emhttp/webGui/scripts/notify -e "unRAID Server Notice" -s "Server Backup" -d "Daily REDBackup completed" -i "normal"

    # Weekly Sunday Backup START
    ############################
    if [ $DAYOFWEEK_NUMERAL_WEEKLY == 7 ]
    then
        rsync -avH --delete --link-dest=$MOUNTPOINT/Daily/ $BACKUPPOINT/ $MOUNTPOINT/Weekly/ 2>&1
        logger Weekly REDBackup Completed -t$PROG_NAME $(date "+%m-%d-%Y %r")
        /usr/local/emhttp/webGui/scripts/notify -e "unRAID Server Notice" -s "Server Backup" -d "Weekly REDBackup completed" -i "normal"
    fi

    # Monthly Backup START
    ############################
    if [ $DAYOFWEEK_NUMERAL_MONTHLY == 1 ]
    then
        rsync -avH --delete --link-dest=$MOUNTPOINT/Daily/ $BACKUPPOINT/ $MOUNTPOINT/Monthly/ 2>&1
        logger Monthly REDBackup Completed -t$PROG_NAME $(date "+%m-%d-%Y %r")
        /usr/local/emhttp/webGui/scripts/notify -e "unRAID Server Notice" -s "Server Backup" -d "Monthly REDBackup completed" -i "normal"
    fi

else

    logger REDBackup Drive Not Mounted -t$PROG_NAME $(date "+%m-%d-%Y %r")
    /usr/local/emhttp/webGui/scripts/notify -e "unRAID Server Notice" -s "Server Backup" -d "Daily REDBackup failed" -i "alert"

fi
```

Comment: Heh, for what it is worth, have a look at my implementation on a similar system here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/41928/regular-backup-snapshots

Comment: (Welcome to CR!) To separate things that are common from those different between controlled blocks, factor out what *is* common - simplifies not only modification, but review, too. (notify: `/usr/local/emhttp/webGui/scripts/notify -e "unRAID Server Notice" -s "Server Backup"`, sync: `rsync -av --delete $SYNCFLAGS $BACKUPPOINT/ $MOUNTPOINT/$MOUNTSUB/ 2>&1`…) What about `rsync` exit code?

Comment: @greybeard your comment belongs in an answer ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Error handling

Error handling is always important,
especially when working with something so important as backups.
In particular, the result of the `rsync` commands is not checked,
the script logs "backup completed" messages,
which doesn't say anything about success or failure.

I suggest to add a check on the exit status of all the `rsync` commands,
and to make the log message reflect the state of success/failure (or simply include the exit code directly).

#### Don't repeat yourself

There are some repeating elements in the code:

- `logger $period REDBackup $result -t$PROG_NAME $(date "+%m-%d-%Y %r")`
- `/usr/local/emhttp/webGui/scripts/notify -e "unRAID Server Notice" -s "Server Backup" -d "$period REDBackup $result" -i "normal"`

I replaced with `$period` and `$result` the parts that could be parameterized.
Extracting these commands to helper functions can greatly reduce duplicated logic, and improve readability.

#### A word on quoting

It's recommended to double-quote all variables used as command arguments.
For example instead of this:

> ```
> rsync -a -v --delete $BACKUPPOINT/ $MOUNTPOINT/Daily/ 2>&1
> ```

It will be safer to write:

```
rsync -a -v --delete "$BACKUPPOINT"/ "$MOUNTPOINT"/Daily/ 2>&1
```

Maybe you know that these variables will always be safe.
But it's good to take this simple precaution anyway,
and make it a habit so it's automatic and you will never fall in a trap of unintended word splitting or globbing.